Fire TV HTML5 Video shows share icon
I'm using a WebView to show HTML5 Video inside an Android app.
On Amazon Fire TV Stick (Android 9, API28) every time the video starts, it shows a grey share icon on the top left:

This is the code:
<video id="window-v-0" class="contain" autoplay="autoplay" poster="" style="position: absolute;width: 100%;height: 100%;"></video>

How can I remove it?

The icon is an OS feature.

@ChukwujiobiCanon I understand, i'm looking for a way to make it disappear. either by flagging the OS to not show it or find a hack to make the video shows on top of it

I doubt the TV has an API or ABI for this, much less from WebView.
